# ActionScript 3 | hitTestObject with switch

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

Is it possible to check the status of `hitTestObject` using `switch` ?

I tried this way:

```
function choosenArea(): void {
    switch mc_wheel.pointer.hitTestObject {
        case mc_wheel.circle.part_cyan:
            trace('cyan');
            break;

        case mc_wheel.circle.part_blue:
            trace('green');
            break;

        case mc_wheel.circle.part_blue:
            trace('blue');
            break;

        case mc_wheel.circle.part_purple:
            trace('purple');
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hittest has no status
it is a function that returns something

Knowing the syntax of a language is a fundamental necessity to work with it.
Your use of brackets seems to be all over the place.

To call the function of the object, you use these brackets: ( )

example:

```
mc_wheel.pointer.hitTestObject(mc_wheel.circle.part_cyan);
```

If you want to know the return value for other parameters, you have to call the function again:

```
mc_wheel.pointer.hitTestObject(mc_wheel.circle.part_blue);
```

There's no way around this. If you have many objects to pass as parameters, you'd incorporate a datas tructure to hold them. An array could be such data structure:

```
var parts:Array = [mc_wheel.circle.part_cyan, mc_wheel.circle.part_blue/*, and so on ...*/];
```

Then iterate with a for loop to pass each element to the function:

```
for each (part in parts)
{
        mc_wheel.pointer.hitTestObject(part);
}
```

This is a general strategy:
First make get it to work with one object.
If you want to do it with many such object, put them all into an array and then treat each element as you did with the single one object.